# Ionic native contacts cordova plugin deprecated? Any alternatives solution?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

App is not open.

I have read that the cordova-plugin-contacts has been deprecated. What solutions are there to find a list of the contacts on the device? I want to have the 'allow contacts' modal to pop open click 'allow' then get the contacts array from device.

So far I found how to implement the plugin only to have my app crash when calling the function. Seems like it wont work because the plugin is deprecated (no longer supported).

Comment: solve! i have use npm install @ionic-native/contacts@5.22.0